# How to convert from multidimensional data nc file data to three column format

Tags: python, r, matlab, multidimensional-array, netcdf

Does anyone can help me, I read data from .nc (netcdf) file in matlab R2013b.
and I get this kind of variable

```
Variables:
    time     
           Size:       1x1
           Dimensions: time
           Datatype:   double
           Attributes:
                       units    = 'hours since 0001-01-01 01:00:00.0'
                       calendar = 'gregorian'
    latitude 
           Size:       801x1
           Dimensions: latitude
           Datatype:   single
           Attributes:
                       units = 'degrees_north'
    longitude
           Size:       1501x1
           Dimensions: longitude
           Datatype:   single
           Attributes:
                       units = 'degrees_east'
     DEN      
           Size:       1501x801x1
           Dimensions: longitude,latitude,time
           Datatype:   single
           Attributes:
                       least_significant_digit = 1
                       long_name               = 'Density'
                       units                   = 'Density Index'
     HGH      
           Size:       1501x801x1
           Dimensions: longitude,latitude,time
           Datatype:   single
           Attributes:
                       least_significant_digit = 1
                       long_name               = 'High level'
                       units                   = 'm'   
....etc
```

and i need format like this:

```
longitude, latitude = DEN
....       ....       ...
....       ....       ...
....       ....       ...
```

to all of data.

I can read every single variable like longitude or DEN, but such as DEN and HGH has three dimensional I don't know how to merge from longitude, latitude and thus value in DEN or HGH.

do you have any suggestion, in case if you have solution in python or R please give the way to read nc file also.

thanks in advance

Comment: What do you want to do with the `time` dimension? Average across it?

Comment: I'm not conversant with ncdf format but  it might be as simple as `df <-expand.grid(lat=latitude-object, lon = longitude-object); df$Den <-as.vector(DEN-object)`. There is an `ncdf4` package to (possibly) assist with importing and extracting those "objects".

Comment: i think time dimension is nothing. just need longitude, latitude and values (DEN,HGH). So i can calculate with my own and other data.

Comment: yeah thats right, i wanna change a simple 2D. I know to process it manually, but be a problem when the data is larger. Still not sure how to make the code to process it. @N1B4 do you have any code example to read and convert it?

Comment: @BondedDust this kind of python program? i have problem when i try to read the data, even already add netcdf4 library

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I was offering comment on R syntax.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: typos

I'd recommend Python for this.

```
import netCDF4

filename = '/your/filename.nc'

# Read in the file
ncfile = netCDF4.Dataset(filename, 'r')
lat = ncfile.variables['latitude'][:,0]
lon = ncfile.variables['longitude'][:,0]
den = ncfile.variables['DEN'][:,:,0]

nlat, nlon = len(lat), len(lon)
# den is now 2D
for y in range(nlat):
    for x in range(nlon):
        print('Lat:{0}, Lon:{1}, DEN:{2}'.format(lat[y], lon[x], den[x,y]))

ncfile.close()
```

Comment: i have and error here, after ncfile close():


Lat:-15.0, Lon:90.0, den0.0:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#33>", line 3, in <module>
    print('Lat:{0}, Lon:{1}, den{2}:'.format(lat[y], lon[x], den[x,y]))

IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size

...

Comment: Sorry - just saw that you need read in the zeroth time index for the lat and lon variables. Try the edited code now.

Comment: File "<pyshell#49>", line 4
    ncfile.close()
   ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: Python loops are defined by a tabbed indentation. Make sure in your script they are tabs and not spaces (which is probably happening if you copy and paste this code directly into a terminal).

Comment: im sorry, i just try some way. but still meet this problem.

 lat = ncfile.variables['latitude'][:,0]
  File "netCDF4.pyx", line 2466, in netCDF4.Variable.__getitem__ (netCDF4.c:22943)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\netCDF4_utils.py", line 203, in _StartCountStride
    raise ValueError("slicing expression exceeds the number of dimensions of the variable")
ValueError: slicing expression exceeds the number of dimensions of the variable

Comment: Where can the netCDF file be found?  It's hard to diagnose exactly without having some data available.

Comment: In the MTS_IR.nc file, `time` is the first dimension, so would need to be read in as `IR[0,:,:]`. `latitude` and `longitude` are 1D, i.e. `latitude[:]` and `longitude[:]`. Use `ncdump filename.nc | more` to examine the contents of netCDF files before reading in.

Comment: okay thanks, i understand about this concept. thanks a lot @NIB4

Answer (score 0):

In R, you can do it quite simply using package `reshape` and `ncdf` (in this example, since you didn't provide a netcdf file, I'll use NOAA yearly air temperature dataset):

```r
library(ncdf)
download.file("ftp://ftp.cdc.noaa.gov/Datasets/ncep/air.2004.nc",destfile="air.nc")
nc <- open.ncdf("air.nc") #Open the netcf file
dat <- get.var.ncdf(nc,'air') #Grabbing the data, in your case replace 'air' with 'DEN'
dat <- dat[,,1,1] #To simulate your 2D data, in your case you already have 2D data so you can skip that
lat <- get.var.ncdf(nc,'lat') #Grabbing the latitude, in your case replace 'lat' with 'latitude'
lon <- get.var.ncdf(nc,'lon') #Grabbing the longitude, in your case replace 'lon' with 'longitude'
```

At this point your data is a matrix with unnamed dimension. Let's name them according to your longitude and latitude:

```
colnames(dat) <- lat
rownames(dat) <- lon
```

Then what you're looking for is simply the result of:

```
library(reshape) 
melt(dat)
```